# How can I return a whole mysql result set, and one at a time set each row as an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

```
foreach($scraperSites as $site) {

    //$scraperWriter->addSite( new ScraperSite($site) );
    print_r($site);

}
```

scraperSites is the array of all sites from the mySQL database; I'm trying to keep $site as an array, (but only with one row worth of data), add it to an object, then move on to the next row.

Comment: What's wrong with your current method?

Comment: print_r($site) displays a string, I need $site to be an array to pass to my object

Comment: your array is $scraperSites then

Comment: $scraperSites contains all rows... I want to grab ALL rows from the database, then assign each individual row to their own associative array.

Comment: "$scraperSites contains all rows" who told you that? and if it's true, just change the code that take result from the database. And I hate site scrapers. No even basic knowledge to build own site but greedy to take some other people job results

Comment: why not converting it into array before using? `if(!is_array($site)){ $site=array($site); }`

Comment: http://pastie.org/925918 -- Here's the code.

Col. Shrapnel: I don't care how you feel about scrapers, I do what my job asks of me, and scrapers can be used for many things.

Comment: So, you could steal and kill just if your job asks?

Comment: It's not stealing, we are building a website for a client that checks another website for UPDATES which will then display new XML feeds.  Grow up.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code, I think this is your problem:

```
public static function getScrapedSites($db) {

    $query = "select * from sites";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $scrapedSites = $result->fetch_assoc();

    return $scrapedSites;

}
```

I believe this will *always* return a single row. You need to loop over the results with `fetch_assoc()` and append the results to an array.

```
public static function getScrapedSites($db) {

    $query = "select * from sites";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $scrapedSites = array();

    foreach($result->fetch_assoc() as $site) {
      $scrapedSites[] = $site;
    }

    return $scrapedSites;
}
```

You said that `$site` was outputting a string in your example. This is because your `foreach` loop was iterating over the db fields in the associative array.

Comment: Thanks :)  Obvious mistake, I've been concentrating so much on learning OOP that I've forgotten some basic principles.